# Mocha test express startup

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

My express server throws an Error, if there are parameters missing (e.g. the DB URI). I want to test in Mocha that it actually threw the errors, but I don't know how I can make Mocha do that.

```
if(!parameters.db) {
    throw new Error('Please provide a db URI');
}
```

I have a test setup like this:

```
it('Throws Error when no db URI provided in production mode', function () {
    expect(require('../server')).to.throw();
    done();
});
```

When my Express app throws the error, the error is thrown into the console and the test fails (in fact, it doesn't end).

---

The other problem I have is that Express only checks for the parameters if the environment is in production mode. I have tried to set the process environment to production inside the test suite, but when I run it, the `NODE_ENV` is still set to 'test'.

```
before(function() {
    env = process.env;
    // This doesn't really set the environment when I run the tests.
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to test for an exception that is not handled within your application try wrapping your invocation in a [try/catch](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_try_catch.asp) and returning an error if the error isn't thrown.

```js
it('Throws Error when no db URI provided in production mode', function () {
  let threwError = false;
  try {
    // create the server that throws the Error
    require('../server');
  } catch (err) {
    threwError = true;
  }
  expect(threwError, 'Didn\'t throw an error, when DB URI is empty').to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution-approach worked, but I have updated your code fixing some parts that didn't work and making it simpler (in my opinion).

Comment: That is a bit simpler, but you still have a bug - you need to define `threwError` outside the try/catch if you want to `expect()` it outside the try/catch.